I2C Scanner does not recognize LCD screen with 1602 I2C module
I'm sorry to ask this, as it has been asked many times, but I can't get the Arduino micro board to recognize my LCD screens. I've tried using two different LCD screens and two different Arduino micros. I've changed the cables. I even swapped the SCL-SDA around if I'm confusing them somehow. Still getting the mocking:
"Scanning...
No I2C devices found"
I've also tried connecting the cables directly to the Arduino pins, suspecting the breadboard to be faulty.
I measured with the multimeter, and there is a 4.7 ohms resistor between the VCC and the SCL-SDA pins.
And I'm out of ideas.

For Arduino Micro, I2C interface is not on A4 and A5 as per your connection, it is on D3 (SCL) and D2 (SDA). See the official pinmap.
Arduino Micro shares the same pin configuration as Leonardo which you can find here Leonando.

Oh. I feel terribly stupid. Thank you.
